# How to select all column in tables with count of certain column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming that I have these column :

1. Form_ID
2. Product_ID
3. Date

P.S : Each Form_ID can have more than 1 Product_ID , and I want to get all data sorted by number of occurence of Product_ID. I've tried some query like,

```
SELECT * , COUNT(Product_ID) AS indicator
from my_database.inv_table
GROUP BY (Product_ID)
ORDER BY indicator DESC
```

Any thoughts and help ? Thank you.

Comment: show example of input and expected output, please. it will make question much easier to understand

Comment: @ASh Sorry for not describe it clear enough. You can say Form_IDs like 'F09123' , 'F21378' , 'F25632' , etc. , and for Product_IDs, let's say 'P0001' , 'P0002' , 'P0003' , etc. What I want to get is all the data (Form_ID , Product_ID , Date) sorted by number of occurences of Product_ID. Does this help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Count(*) Over (Partition by Product_ID)`:

```
SELECT Form_ID, Product_ID, Date, 
       Indicator = Count(*) Over (Partition by Product_ID)
FROM my_database.inv_table
ORDER BY Indicator DESC
```

You don't need to select the `Indicator`-column if you don't want, you can use `Count(*) Over (Partition by Product_ID)` also in the `ORDER BY`.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: What if there are 10 columns ? Do I have to describe all the columns ? or, Can I replace the columns with * as usual ?

Comment: @Ray: of course you can use `*` but [you should not](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated sub-query to do the counting:

```
SELECT t1.*, (select COUNT(*) from my_database.inv_table t2
              where t1.Form_ID = t2.Form_ID) AS indicator
from my_database.inv_table t1
ORDER BY indicator DESC
```

Comment: This would work, but check out the `over` clause from Tim Schmelter's answer :)

Comment: Please explain the logic here, so I can understand. :)

Comment: @jarlh But, I think it should be t1.Product_ID = t2.Product_ID , wasn't it ? Because I count based on Product_ID. CMIIW

Comment: Add some sample data and expected result to the question, and I can adjust my answer.